# How to connect to a network of activemq brokers from a client application?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have setup a network of brokers in activemq, how do i connect to that from my client application

I tried with

network:static:(tcp://master1.IP:61616,tcp://master2.IP:61617) and

but I get the following exception

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [network];
```

With

static:(tcp://master1.IP:61616,tcp://master2.IP:61617)

I get exception

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [static];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Clients wishing to failover to a static list of broker instances, should use the failover:// transport instead." (from : http://activemq.apache.org/static-transport-reference.html)

so the correct syntax would be:

failover:(tcp://master1.IP:61616,tcp://master2.IP:61617)

Answer (score 1):

For Connecting in Network of Brokers, we can use Multicast as follows:
In ActiveMQ.xml:

```
<transportConnectors>
<transportConnector name="openwire"  uri="tcp://IP1:61616" discoveryUri="multicast://default?group=GROUPNAME"/>
</transportConnectors>

<networkConnectors>
<networkConnector uri="multicast://default?group=GROUPNAME"/>
</networkConnectors>
```

And in the client side API:

```
discovery:(multicast://default?group=GROUPNAME)
```